# VSTO Localization issue .Findnext

Tags: excel, localization, vsto

I am encountering a strange issue with the .Findnext in Excel VSTO solution. The code is working very well with the English language setting but it fails with the below error under German language setting.

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

When Investigated, the *EndRng = .FindNext(EndRng)* is returning nothing. How is it possible that this block works under English setting but not under German?

```
Dim StartRng As Excel.Range, EndRng As Excel.Range
Dim wrkSheet As Worksheet
Dim wb As Excel.Workbook = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook
Dim xlapp As Excel.Application = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application

Dim FormulaToFind As String = FormulaToLocal(FormulaString)
wrkSheet.Range(wrkSheet.Cells(RowStart, ColStart), wrkSheet.Cells(RowEnd, ColEnd)).Select()       
With xlapp.ActiveWindow.Selection
          StartRng = .Find(FormulaToFind, LookIn:=Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlFormulas, LookAt:=Excel.XlLookAt.xlPart)
          If Not StartRng Is Nothing Then
             EndRng = StartRng
             StartAddress = StartRng.Address
             Do
                EndAddress = EndRng.Address
                EndRng = .FindNext(EndRng)
                Loop While Not EndRng Is Nothing And EndRng.Address <> StartAddress
          End If
      End With
```

*Below is the Function to convert formula to local*

```
 Public Function FormulaToLocal(ByVal RefFormula As String) As String
    Dim wb As Excel.Workbook = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook
    Dim TmpSheet As String = "TmpSheet"
    wb.Worksheets(TmpSheet).Range("AZ1").Formula = RefFormula 
    FormulaToLocal= wb.Worksheets(TmpSheet).Range("AZ1").Formulalocal
    wb.Worksheets(TmpSheet).Range("AZ1").value = ""
End Function
```

Comment: You need to give us an example we can use to repro. What's `FormulaString`? Are you sure you're getting back the value you expect from `FormulaToLocal?

Comment: @CindyMeister the value of FormulaString is "=TRANSPOSE(MMULT(V49:X51,TRANSPOSE(C48:E48)))". The function FormulaToLocal returns "=MTRANS(MMULT(V49:X51,MTRANS(C48:E48)))" which is the German equivalent. The function is working exactly as intended. The formula is repeated in 3 consecutive rows as a matrix formula. I need to check that the formula is applied 3 times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft acknowledged some issue with this. They are investigating with the senior engineers. Below is the alternative solution suggested by Andreas from Microsoft Community.

```
With rngData
    StartRng = .Find(FormulaToFind, LookIn:=Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlFormulas, LookAt:=Excel.XlLookAt.xlPart,
                     SearchOrder:=Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows, SearchDirection:=Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlNext)
    If Not StartRng Is Nothing Then
        EndRng = StartRng
        StartAddress = StartRng.Address
        Do
            EndAddress = EndRng.Address
            EndRng = .Find(FormulaToFind, After:=EndRng, LookIn:=Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlFormulas, LookAt:=Excel.XlLookAt.xlPart,
        SearchOrder:=Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows, SearchDirection:=Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlNext)

        Loop While Not EndRng Is Nothing And EndRng.Address <> StartAddress
    End If
End With
```